# How can I loop through li elements of a ul in Testcafe

Tags: automated-testing, testcafe

(translated using Google translate)

I am trying to loop through the `<li>` elements of a `<ul>`, but I cannot make it work.

My HTML:

```
<ul class="sc-iFMziU>
  <li class="sc-keVrkP"</li>
    <p class="sc-cBdUnI">Parrafo 1</p>
  <li class="sc-keVrkP"</li>
    <p class="sc-cBdUnI">Parrafo 2</p>
</ul>
```

My Testcafe code:

```
const ul = Selector('ul')
const li = ul.child('li')

for (let i = 0: i<ul.child('li').length; i++) {
  console.log(ul.child().parent(i))
}
```

But I can't get it to print anything.

---

(Original question in Spanish)
Estoy intentando recorrer los diferentes li que estan dentro del ul pero no consigo la forma:

HTML:

```
<ul class="sc-iFMziU>
  <li class="sc-keVrkP"</li>
    <p class="sc-cBdUnI">Parrafo 1</p>
  <li class="sc-keVrkP"</li>
    <p class="sc-cBdUnI">Parrafo 2</p>
</ul>
```

Con testcafe tengo:

```
const ul = Selector('ul')
const li = ul.child('li')

for (let i = 0: i<ul.child('li').length; i++) {
  console.log(ul.child().parent(i))
}
```

Pero no logro que me imprima nada

Comment: I suppose questions should be in English here. On the other hand, I can't find any written rule about it in e.g. Tour, or the Help Center. Perhaps it's just an unwritten rule when we all sort of expect people should and will speak English.

Comment: @pavelsaman https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/

Comment: Please update your question to English

Comment: @PDHide: thank you for the link. I guess the same goes for SQA here and all other stackexchange communities. It makes sense. So perhaps it's better if questions are in English, but it's not a strict rule.

Comment: I have translated using Google translate with minimal editing for readability. The original Spanish is preserved in the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no length property for selector,

```
const li = ul.child('li')
```

returns a selector object. So,  instead of length use count and i am not sure what you trying to do by printing parent object , so printing innerText instead

```
for (let i = 0: i< (await ul.child('li').count); i++) {
  console.log(await ul.child().innerText)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Testcafe has [an example](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-examples/blob/master/examples/iterate-over-list-elements/index.js) which shows how to do this. The second example at that url shows the way to do this.

The questioner's code re-computes the count each iteration, and forgets that .child() returns an array.

The "answer" here shares similar misunderstandings to the question, and won't work either.